# Cannot change manifest tag with custom gradle task

Tags: android, gradle, variant

```
class ReleaseTask extends DefaultTask {
 @TaskAction
 def releaseTask() {
    def android = project.extensions.android
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def mergedFlavor = variant.getMergedFlavor()
        mergedFlavor.manifestPlaceholders = [UMENG_APPKEY: '', UMENG_MESSAGE_SECRET: '']

        variant.buildConfigField("boolean", "enableChangeEnvDialog", "false")
    }
  }
}

project.tasks.create("releaseTask", ReleaseTask)
```

the code above is my custom gradle task.

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        zipAlignEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [UMENG_APPKEY:'',UMENG_MESSAGE_SECRET:'']
    }
}
```

this code is my buildType block configration.

Now my problem is when I build my release apk, I used

```
./gradlew clean releaseTask assembleRelease
```

but in the release apk I didn't get the placeHolder in task but the keys in buildType/release block. but the code

```
variant.buildConfigField("boolean", "enableChangeEnvDialog", "false")
```

was effected.

I want to know why , and how to code the task to make it correct.
anything will be helpful.
thanks